# How to pick the next element in a list at a random time?

Tags: python-2.7, list, time

I am making a application that searches google for keywords and appends the URLs from the search into a list. Then post the URL to twitter.

**How do I pick up one URL from the list at a random time per hour, and then pick the next URL in the list sequentially in the next hour at a random time?**

```
import tweepy, time
from google import search

CONSUMER_KEY = 'xxxx'
CONSUMER_SECRET = 'xxxx'

# Create a new Access Token
ACCESS_TOKEN = 'xxxx' 
ACCESS_SECRET = 'xxxx'


auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

#search google for url key links

lst = [] #list holding URL
for url in search('python', stop=20):
    lst.append(url)
    print(url)

lst  = [ x for x in lst if "wiki" not in x ]

# What the bot will tweet
for line in lst: 
    api.update_status(line)
    print line
    print '...'
    time.sleep(1) 

print "All done!"
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What exactly are you stuck on?

Comment: @glibdud I am stuck on, how do I pick one element from the list at a random time per hour/every hour

Comment: There are a lot of steps there, though. Do you need to know how to generate [`random`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/random.html) numbers? Are you just looking for the [`sched`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/sched.html) module?

Comment: @glibdud I just need to know how to schedule at random intervals per hour. I can write a function to pull a item in the in list when the timer goes off

Answer (score 0):

This line of code seems to work, when posting randomly every hour:

```
for line in lst: 
    #api.update_status(line)
    print line
    print '...'
    sleep(random.randint(1,60))
```